# Update variable in Threads in real time as variable updates outside Thread

Tags: python, scope, python-multithreading

So I have a variable that constantly changes in main scope, then I need a thread that checks if the variable that is updated is a certain value. My code looks like this

```
def check():
    global a
    print(if a == 2)

Thread(target=check).start()
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    a = random.randint(3)
```

But in the Thread the **a** variable does not change while the main **a** is constantly changing.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You'll need to fix your syntax error first. When you've done that you need to research Python threads. The threaded *check()* function will execute once then finish. There's no apparent allowance for that

Comment: @Vlad can you explain where is the check() function?

Comment: Yes of course I can. It's in your code